# Unable to update the system using apt

Tags: updates, system, apt

This is what I see when I run `sudo apt-get update` on terminal,

```
 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.28.4.44 80]
 E: El repositorio «http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease» ya no está firmado.
 N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
 N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the GPG key

```
$ wget -q "http://packages.elementary.io/key.asc" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

, then

```
$ sudo apt update
```